# Avoid master page rendering in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I just want to remove master page from report.cshtml. I have written 
like

```
 @{
      Layout= string.Empty;
      }
```

or

```
 @{
      Layout=null;
      }
```

also tried in controller

```
  public ActionResult LLCReportsPopUp(string camp)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Reports/Views/LCCReport.cshtml");
        }
```

But no result, please help.

Answer (score 2):

Copy your `_ViewStart.cshtml` into your Report view folder and then make `Layout = null`. Job done. It will remove the default master layout from your report

```
@{
   // Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    Layout = null;
}
```

`_ViewStart.cshtml` on Views\Report folder overwrites `_ViewStart.cshtml` in Views folder

If you need to assign a second layout instead of removing it you can do it as;

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MySecond_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is simply to create a completely blank layout template and assign that one.